# WinAPI: Trackbar scroll begin notification

Tags: c++, winapi, trackbar

I have a trackbar control in my app and I want to do something when user starts scroll operation (when he clicks on the trackbar's thumb). Since WM_HSCROLL doesn't notify about such event, I was wondering how do I get to know when user starts scrolling. I'd like to avoid processing SB_THUMBTRACK request since thay would mean I'd have to process it all the time when user's scrolling, and I just want to know when he starts doing it.

Comment: Here's a hint: [these are the trackbar notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760149%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#tkb_notifications). Note `TB_ENDTRACK`. (I haven't tried this myself, which is why I'm not giving this as an answer yet.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just process `TB_THUMBTRACK` and ignore all subsequent `TB_THUMBTRACK`s until you get `TB_ENDTRACK`. That's roughly 5-9 lines of code.

For trackbars you also should use the TB_* (trackbar) constants and not the SB_* (scrollbar) constants even if their respective values are the same (e.g. SB_ENDSCROLL == TB_ENDTRACK == 8, SB_THUMBPOSITION == TB_THUMBPOSITION == 4).

Comment: I see. AFAIK it wasn't mentioned in the documentation, but I'll be using these constants from now on. Thank you.